# Hiding informations

Tags: phantom

Good morning, I'm trying to avoid informations from my CV. In particular, I'd like to have a method to substitute my personal address with a black box of the same size of the text. I'm currently using `\phantom` , and I'd like to know whether there exists a way to have a black space instead of a blank space.

Comment: Welcome. // Next time please try preparing a simple piece of code, which a) compiles once we copied it, b) shows your problem, c) discarded all unnecessary parts. This usually improves answers considerably. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Here is a better way to do it:

[image: result]

This is what you get, after copy and paste from the pdf:

```
To censor it .
To blackout it, .
```

For more alternatives see topic `security` at [ctan](https://ctan.org/topic/security), where only `luacensor` may be of interest.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{censor}

\begin{document}

To censor it \censor{censor it}.\\

To blackout it, \blackout{black it out}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like that

```
\newlength{\myboxw}
\newlength{\myboxh}
\newcommand{\blackphantom}[1]%
{\settowidth{\myboxw}{#1}%
\settoheight{\myboxh}{#1}%
\rule{\myboxw}{\myboxh}}

\blackphantom{Hidden Text}
```

would work, but only horizontally (i.e. does not support multi-lines content or text with wrapping/hyphenation). (I think `\phantom` has the same behavior, though...)

Comment: You could simplify this by using one savebox (which is how \phantom,  \settoheight and \settowidth work).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it:

- use packages `xcolor` and `soul` to highlight text via `\hl{}`
- it visually overwrites it

However, if you'd mark, copy and paste the black part into an editor, you still can read it: `strike-out.`

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

\begin{document}

1: Whatever you want to \hl{highlight}.\\

\sethlcolor{black}
2: Whatever you want to strike-\hl{out}.\\

3: Whatever you want to \hl{highlight}.\\% uses current color

\sethlcolor{yellow}% switch "back"
4: Whatever you want to \hl{highlight}.

\end{document}
```

**P.S.**: This may still be an option, as not all users of pdf files even know, less try, they can mark and copy text selections ...

Answer (score 2):

A typesetting-based solution using Lua code can be used to define a custom Open Type font feature which, when switched on for a font, allows the font to replace one glyph (set) with another (set), including ligatures.

[image: censor1]

And:

[image: censor2]

The more traditional "censor's ink block":

[image: censor3]

Requires LuaLaTeX.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\anycxchar{uniEBA3}
\newcommand\anycxcharb{uni2580}
\newcommand\anycxcharc{circlecopyrt}

\directlua {
luaotfload.add_colorscheme("cxscheme",
{
["FF200080"] = {"\anycxchar"},
})
}

\directlua {
luaotfload.add_colorscheme("cyscheme",
{
["FF20A090"] = {"\anycxcharb"},
})
}



\directlua {
luaotfload.add_colorscheme("czscheme",
{
["FF0000"] = {"T_h"},
})
}

\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "anycx",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
        ["a"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["b"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["c"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["d"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["e"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["f"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["g"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["h"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["i"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["j"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["k"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["l"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["m"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["n"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["o"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["p"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["q"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["r"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["s"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["t"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["u"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["v"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["w"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["x"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["y"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["z"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["0"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["1"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["2"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["3"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["4"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["5"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["6"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["7"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["8"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["9"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["r"] = "\anycxchar",
        [","] = "\anycxchar",
        ["."] = "\anycxchar",
        ["/"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["<"] = "\anycxchar",
        [">"] = "\anycxchar",
        ["?"] = "\anycxchar",
        }
    }
}


\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "anycy",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
        ["hyphen"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["a"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["b"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["c"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["d"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["e"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["f"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["g"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["h"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["i"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["j"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["k"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["l"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["m"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["n"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["o"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["p"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["q"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["r"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["s"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["t"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["u"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["v"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["w"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["x"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["y"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["z"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["0"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["1"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["2"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["3"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["4"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["5"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["6"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["7"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["8"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["9"] = "\anycxcharb",
        [32] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["r"] = "\anycxcharb",
        [","] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["."] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["/"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["<"] = "\anycxcharb",
        [">"] = "\anycxcharb",
        ["?"] = "\anycxcharb",
        }
    }
}




\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "anycz2",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
        ["T_h"] = "\anycxcharc",
        }
}}



\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "anycz",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
        ["hyphen"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["a"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["b"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["c"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["d"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["e"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["f"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["g"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["h"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["i"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["j"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["k"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["l"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["m"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["n"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["o"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["p"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["q"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["r"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["s"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["t"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["u"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["v"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["w"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["x"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["y"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["z"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["0"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["1"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["2"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["3"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["4"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["5"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["6"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["7"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["8"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["9"] = "\anycxcharc",
        [32] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["r"] = "\anycxcharc",
        [","] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["."] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["/"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["<"] = "\anycxcharc",
        [">"] = "\anycxcharc",
        ["?"] = "\anycxcharc",
        }
    }
}

\newfontfamily\fany{Clara}[
RawFeature=+anycx,
Colour=cxscheme,
]

\newfontfamily\fancy{FiraMath}[
RawFeature=+anycy,
Colour=cyscheme,
]


\newfontfamily\fancz{AntykwaTorunska}[
RawFeature=+anycz,
]


\newfontfamily\fancza{AntykwaTorunska}[
Ligatures=TeX,
Colour=czscheme,
]

\newfontfamily\fanczb{AntykwaTorunska}[
RawFeature=+anycz;+anycz2,
]


\begin{document}

abcde fghij klmnop qrstu wxyz 1234567890 ,./<>?

\fany


abcde fghij klmnop qrstu wxyz 1234567890 ,./<>?

\lipsum

\newpage
\fancy


abcde fghij klmnop qrstu wxyz 1234567890 ,./<>?

\lipsum



\newpage
\normalfont
Q: What is the question to $1+1=1$?


A: {\fancz The cat sat on the mat.}


\fancza ``Th'' is a ligature: \fanczb The cat sat on the mat.

\end{document}
```