# Replace each letter of a given word with blank boxes

Tags: macros, boxes

I would like a command that takes a word and replaces each letter with a box.

For example, the output of

`The mystery word is \mycommand{hello}.`

should be

The mystery word is □□□□□.

Comment: Maybe you could adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696769/36296

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle,amssymb}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{$\square$}}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\tokencyclexpress#1\endtokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
The mystery word is \mycommand{hello}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

To give an example of fuller possibilities, I provide another example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle,amssymb}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{\fbox{#1}\;}}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\tokencyclexpress#1\endtokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}
The mystery word is \mycommand{hello \textit{Mom}. \textbf{I love you}.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good start, thank you.  Is it possible to make the squares instead editable tcolorboxes or things like that?

Comment: @Garf I am not sure what you mean by "editable"; however, code may be inserted in the character directive in place of `$\square$`, even code than employs the replaced token (denoted as `#1`).  I'll give an example.

Comment: Thanks!  I used editable to mean the ability to manipulate the size of the box or other properties etc.  This answers my question I think the main challenge was knowing how to tell latex to iterate over each character given.

Comment: @Garf That is the function of the `tokcycle` package...to iterate over a string of tokens.  In these examples, I only alter the result for "Characters".  However, Groups, Macros, and Spaces are also detected and can have their own special treatment.

Answer (score 5):

For good measure, a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

Note that the argument of `\mycommand`  can contain general utf8-encoded characters, not just ASCII-encoded characters; thus, `\mycommand{你好世界}` is entirely ok. Note further that because `\directlua` and `\luastring` are expandable, so is `\mycommand`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\square' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastring' macro
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\directlua{ 
    tex.sprint (( unicode.utf8.gsub ( \luastring{#1} , "." , "$\\square$" ) )) }}

\begin{document}
The mystery word is \mycommand{hello}, or is it \mycommand{你好世界}?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically a one-liner with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand{\textsquare}{% from amsthm
  \begingroup \usefont{U}{msa}{m}{n}\symbol{3}\endgroup
}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mystery}{m}
 {
  \text_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \textsquare \kern1pt } \unkern
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The mystery word is \mystery{hello}

The mystery word is \mystery{équipe}

The mystery word is \mystery{naïve}

\end{document}
```

[image]